# JQuery access value of an input

Tags: jquery

How can i access corresponding value of an input box residing in `#first` and `#second` on click of the `.glyphicon-pencil`, i.e. it has to give the value 90909 when I click on .glyphicon-pencil on first `<tr>` here and 1000125 on click of second `<tr>`

```
<tr id_gl_code="66" class="success">
     <td id="first" id_gl_code="66"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="90909"></td>
     <td id="second"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="some xyz"></td>
     <td id="third"><span id_gl_code="66" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
     <td id="fourth"><span id_gl_code="66" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr id_gl_code="67" class="success">
     <td id="first"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="1000125"></td>
     <td id="second"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="miscellanious income expenses"></td>
     <td id="third"><span  id_gl_code="67" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
     <td id="fourth"><span  id_gl_code="67" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: id should be unique..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-pencil',function(){
var first=$(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(0) input').val()
var second=$(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val()
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hJ6Fx/)

Comment: This is unlikely to produce the expected results due to the duplicate IDs